# GIT Log or Commit Monitor

Tags: windows, git, commit

I'm trying to find a Git Commit Monitor for Windows. Does anyone know whether one exists?

Ideally it would essentially monitor the log and notify when a new commit has occurred.

Comment: Where is the repository that you are trying to monitor? On some remote site? How do you want to be notified? By Email?

Comment: hi - yeah on a remote site. its a remote repository on a windows box - cant figure out how it can notify me ?

Comment: I am using TortiseGIT and was hoping for a simple way to get update notifications .... a fair few commits per day?

Comment: Still no valid solution :(

Comment: Here is a replacement : https://github.com/regisbsb/scm-notifier

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just use the GIT hook [`post-commit`](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

[githooks(5) Manual Page](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks)

Comment: Hi :) Not sure what you mean ?

Comment: hi yeah i did - but little unsure how to use it ? its command line only or ?

Comment: @jitter, even if he did, you'll have to wade through some jargon to know what it all means. I had to try several times before I could get the pre-commit hook to run a script I wanted... but that could be me offcourse.

Comment: @Tom, yes, it's command line. I started with TortoiseGit also but find myself using the Git Bash command line more and more. If you want all the bells and whistles, that is the only way. As a sidenote, once you get the gist of it, you don't want to go back for your day to day git activities.

Comment: that should read "go back to the GUI for you day to day git activities.

Comment: @anonymousVoter: If you downvote please give a reason also in a comment. How else should I know what you disliked about my answer

Comment: @jitter i'm guessing the downvotes are because, the OP asked for a windows monitor that pops up when something has been committed on a 'remote' repository. adding a hook on the remote server will allow him to get an email at best, not a windows based notification on his local computer

Answer (score 19):

I have started an open source project to build a tool that does this. **SourceLog** is a .NET v4.0 WPF application that monitors version control system change logs.  The application uses a plugin model to support multiple version control systems.  There are currently plugins for Git, GitHub (via the API), Subversion, Perforce, and TFS 2010.

[image: SourceLog main window]

The application polls each "subscribed" repository for changes and displays a "toast" notification panel when new changes are detected.

The project is hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/tomhunter-gh/SourceLog) and the app can be installed via the ClickOnce installer hosted on [AppHarbor](https://sourcelog.apphb.com/).  There is more information available on my [blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20160428173117/http://www.unhandledexception.info/sourcelog/).

Comment: would love to be able to run this on my Mac... would it run under Mono?

Comment: It's built using WPF framework, which is only available on Windows. The Mono project has a status page on their implementation plans; http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/wpf/

Comment: Does it work with ssh protocol, like this: ssh://root@192.168.10.120/foldername/.git

Comment: The setup on AppHarbor isn't accessible anymore :(

Comment: Please, can you put the setup online again ? :)

Answer (score 4):

The best would be to use the post-receive hook.

On your repository on the server, you have to put a shell script named 'post-receive' in the .git/hooks directory. This script will be invoked each time something is pushed and it's passed argument via stdin in the form

There are examples scripts provided with recent version of git. Look in:

```
/usr/share/doc/git-core/contrib/hooks/post-receive-email
```

On windows, look at the path of your install to find it ...

Comment: I think this might be the better(simpler) answer for this question.

Comment: How would one go about doing this for a repo hosted on github?

Answer (score 3):

There is git monitor which displays popup notifications. It should work in Windows using [Growl](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/): https://github.com/spajus/gitmon

Answer (score 2):

https://gitmonitor.com

This site has a tool like what you're looking for... I came here trying to find info to see if it's good or not.

Comment: Looks promising, but doesn't have a trial or free option. Currently minimum is $5/month.

Comment: UPDATE - looks like they now offer a 30 day free trial @Danijel

Comment: it seems it only works with github and you have to give them your credentials... sucks

Answer (score 1):

See this blog for a approach using Growl, Cygwin, Ruby and Git-Notifier.

http://hsiliev.blogspot.com/2011/03/git-notifier-on-windows.html

Answer (score 0):

Try RSS or Atom feeds and any common RSS reader (e.g. Mozilla Thunderbird). Of course, you have some web server (like gitweb CGI script) which provides that.